# React Native cannot delete user data even after re-authenticating with signInWithPhoneNumber()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm calling auth().currentUser.delete() to delete a user after they're authenticated using signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber). What I'm seeing in the real-time db is the account being deleted but not the data. The data structure is very simple:

```
<userid>: {
    userName:"",
    ...

}

export const authDeleteAccountSettings = async () => {
  var user = auth().currentUser;
  return deleteAllAlarms(user).then(async function (user1) {
    return await user1.delete().then(
      function () {
        return true;
      },
      function (error) {
        // An error happened.
        console.log('error : ' + error);
        return false;
      },
    );
  });
};

const deleteAllAlarms = async userData => {
  return database()
    .ref('/users/' + userData.uid)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      if (!!data && data?.hasOwnProperty('alarmList')) {
        const entries = Object.values(data.alarmList);
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
          database()
            .ref('/alarms/' + entries[i])
            .remove();
        }
      }
      return userData;
    });
};
```

check auth status

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);

    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    if (user) {
      goToSettingsScreen();
    }
  }
```

In the Firebase console, the data lights up like it wants to delete the user, but just doesn't. Does this problem have anything to do with phone number login? I've witnessed this problem both in ios and android. firebase app 18.4.0. React Native 0.72.5